# Jenkins Pipeline: How to allocate multiple nodes for a single test - distributed test orchestration

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

**This is not a normal "Run this job on many slaves" question!**

Cookie-cutter answers will not do.

#### Use Case

I am attempting to use the Jenkins Pipeline to instrument a test for distributed software that involves one "client" and many "servers" by allocating Jenkins slaves for those roles, running the components on the slaves and then tearing it all down.  We can pretend that "servers" will run a web server and "client" runs "wget" against them.

#### Considerations

I'm using the scripted pipeline (not declarative).  Essentially I need all the "servers" to be up when I run the client logic on the "client" node.

Obviously sequential **node{}** blocks won't work because I need all slaves to be up concurrently.  Parallel may work, and I am open to this option, but it seems that it will be hard to debug.

#### My solution

So here is what I've come up with so far.  This is a simplified example, there might be logic after each *node* closure (set up each server) and near the end of each *node* closure (clean up each server), or it can all be done by the client, doesn't really matter.

```
def allocatedServerList = []
// Allocate 3 "servers" and then 1 client. Keep servers allocated.
node {
   allocatedServerList << env.NODE_NAME
   node {
      allocatedServerList << env.NODE_NAME
      node {
         allocatedServerList << env.NODE_NAME
         node {
            //this is the client
            sh "run some client work against ${allocatedServerList}"
            //eg: ssh to each server, start some service, pound it for a while, shut them down
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Surprisingly, this works fine.

Can anyone suggest a **better approach**?  The downside with nested code is that you can't change the number of nodes easily (without recursive methods, which make it unreadable)

Answer (score -1):

to run on all nodes you can use something like this:

[image: Trigger Job On All Nodes]

The example shows how to trigger jobs on all Jenkins nodes from Pipeline.

Summary: * The script uses NodeLabel Parameter plugin to pass the job name to the payload job. * Node list retrieval is being performed using Jenkins API, so it will require script approvals in the Sandbox mode
To see this example from jenkins.io please visit : [Trigger Job On All Nodes](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#trigger-job-on-all-nodes)

Comment: Yep, if i missunderstood what you are trying to accomplish, can you give more clarification ?

Comment: I've attempted to make the question as clear as possible.  If there is something that isn't clear, please tell me what to clarify.